# Gunicorn Command Line Error inGoogle App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm getting an endless stream of the following errors after deploying a Flask/Python3/Postgres app to app engine standard environment. The warning about Psycopg2 package is of concern, but not what's causing the app to fail to run. Rather, it's the invalid command line arguments to gunicorn, which are supplied by GAE, not by me. Is anyone able to deploy a Python3 Flask that uses Postgres to the Standard environment successfully?

Here's the log file output:

```
2018-12-11 02:51:37 +0000] [3738] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3738
2018-12-11 02:51:37 default[20181210t140744]  /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2018-12-11 02:51:37 default[20181210t140744]    """)
2018-12-11 02:51:38 default[20181210t211942]  usage: gunicorn [-h] [--debug] [--args]
2018-12-11 02:51:38 default[20181210t211942]  gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: main:app --workers 1 -c /config/gunicorn.py
2018-12-11 02:51:38 default[20181210t211942]  [2018-12-11 02:51:38 +0000] [882] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 882)
```

Comment: Can you show your `app.yaml` file? Do you have an `entrypoint` in it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, if `entrypoint` is not defined in app.yaml, App Engine will look for an app called `app` in `main.py`. If you look at the official code sample in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/hello_world), it addresses it in the main.py file by declaring:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Alternatively, this can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml pointing to another file. For example, if you declare app in a file called prod:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT prod.app
```

You'll find additional details about the entrypoint configuration [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup).

Answer (score 0):

From the comment and answer above, It looked like the problem had to be in my app. I confirmed that by running gunicorn locally on a bare-bones app without difficulty, but failing when running the real app.

One culprit turned out to be the use of *argparse*, which I was using so I could add a "debug" argument to the command line when working locally. Moving that code to the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section made the app run fine when using gunicorn locally.

But it still fails when deployed to GAE:

```
2018-12-12 20:09:16 default[20181212t094625]  [2018-12-12 20:09:16 +0000] [8145] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8145
2018-12-12 20:09:16 default[20181212t094625]  /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2018-12-12 20:09:16 default[20181212t094625]    """)
2018-12-12 20:09:16 default[20181212t094625]  [2018-12-12 20:09:16 +0000] [8286] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8286
2018-12-12 20:09:16 default[20181212t094625]  /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2018-12-12 20:09:16 default[20181212t094625]    """)
2018-12-12 20:09:19 default[20181212t094625]  usage: gunicorn [-h] [--debug] [--args]
2018-12-12 20:09:19 default[20181212t094625]  gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: -b :8081 main:app
2018-12-12 20:09:19 default[20181212t094625]  [2018-12-12 20:09:19 +0000] [8145] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8145)
```

Here’s app.yaml (minus the environment variable for SendGrid):

```
runtime: python37
env: standard
#threadsafe: true
entrypoint: gunicorn --workers 2 --bind :5000 main:app

#runtime_config:
#  python_version: 3

# This beta setting is necessary for the db hostname parameter to be able to handle a URI in the
# form “/cloudsql/...” where ... is the instance given here:
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: provost-access-148820:us-east1:cuny-courses
```